# Debugging the network state changes in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have to have netowrk connected/disconnected state changes in my react-native application. ATM I'm only interested in the  android case.

I use the remote JS debugger (either the react-native one base on chrome or https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) because debugging with adb logcat is very impractical.

But the debugger uses the network to reach the application (I'm debugging the app in an emulator from the host, but I suppose the physical mobile would have the same problem?).
So when I disconnect the emulator from the network, I just disconnect the debugger from the application.

How would that be done ? Is there a way to have different network interfaces on the mobile and use one for the debugger and one for the mobile data, for example?

Comment: A bit confused. Are you trying to confirm if you have received data from internet and get error message if not connected?

Comment: Your only real solution is to use a simulator or render debug messages on the screen/alerts.

Comment: @blacksun: I'm trying to debug the actions my code does in cases I'm connected, disconnected, and the action of my network state listeners.

Comment: @MattyK14 what do you mean by "simulator"?

Comment: @mleduque an Android simulator/emulator.